# Swift: Constant's internal implementation

Tags: swift

In swift, how is constants implemented? 
I read [this article](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7), which says

> In Swift, constants are generally implemented as (inlined) function calls.

I am not clear of this statement.
Does Swift use a special approach to make constants?
Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with "getter" and "setter" methods from other languages, such as Java? If a variable is made public in a language like Java, it's exposed to other classes to access directly. In the future, if this variable has to be changed, there's no way to do so without changing all of the other classes dependent upon. With getter/setter methods, dummy implementations can be made that don't do anything besides read/write the value. In the case that a change needs to be made, the implementation of these methods can be changed without effecting the public API of the class.

Swift implements variables with "properties", which are like a backing private variable with public getter/setter methods that are automatically generated. In the future, you can replace a property with a computer property with a special getter/setter implementation, without effecting the public API of the class, just like before. The difference here is that you don't need to write all of the default getters/setters yourself.

Comment: Do you mean in Swift "property" has automatically generated getter and setter? Assuming a difference between `var` and `let` in Swift, `var` has both a getter and setter whereas `let` has only getter.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. `var` can also have `willSet` and `didSet` hooks

Comment: So, in the article, does the inlined function call mean just a getter?

Comment: Yep, it's the getter is just a function. In most cases, it's inlined automatically